# Increment value in sql server

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm new to sql server here i have sql query to alter the table like

```
ALTER TABLE `ct_email_templates`
MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=30;
```

How can i write this query into sql server?

I tried the below one, is this correct or not?

```
ALTER TABLE ct_email_templates
add id int IDENTITY(1,30) NOT NULL
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure on what `AUTO_INCREMENT=30` does, but if this means that every row added the number should be raised by 30, then in Sql server that's the second parameter of the `Identity` - meaning it should be `IDENTITY(1, 30)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an identity to an existing column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049210/adding-an-identity-to-an-existing-column)

Comment: modified check it once@zoharPeled

Answer (score 0):

as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708484/whats-the-purpose-of-setting-auto-increment-to-30-when-creating-table) AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ensures your next value is 31

so your current  query should be like below

```
ALTER TABLE ct_email_templates
add id int IDENTITY(30,1) NOT NULL
```

this tells SQLServer to start your identity values from 30